# get and validate checkboxes and radio buttons values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I've got the following form:

```
<form id="frmEnquiry" action="" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <div id="mail-status"></div>
    <div class="w-row">
        <div class="w-col w-col-3 w-col-stack form-padding-left no-left-padding ">
            <div class="form-label">Name:</div>
            <input
                type="text" name="userName" id="userName"
                class="demoInputBox width"  placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div class="  w-col w-col-3 w-col-stack no-left-padding">
            <div class="form-label">Phone Number:</div>
            <input
                type="text" name="phone" id="phone"
                class="demoInputBox width" placeholder="phone">
        </div>
        <div class="  w-col w-col-3 w-col-stack no-left-padding">
            <div class="form-label">E-Mail:</div>
            <input
                type="text" name="userEmail" id="userEmail"
                class="demoInputBox width" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="  w-col w-col-3 w-col-stack no-left-padding">
            <div class="form-label">ZIP / City of job site:</div>
            <input
                type="text" name="zip" id="zip"
                class="demoInputBox width" placeholder="zip">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w-row">
        <div class="w-col w-col-3 w-col-stack form-padding-left no-left-padding">
            <div class="form-label ">Date you would like to set up for: </div>
            <input class="demoInputBox width" name="Date" id="Date" type="date">
        </div>
        <div class="w-col w-col-3 w-col-stack no-left-padding">
            <div class="form-label">Preferred Appointment Time:</div>
            <input class="demoInputBox width" name="Time" id="Time" type="time">
        </div>
        <div class="w-col w-col-3 w-col-stack no-left-padding"></div>
        <div class="w-col w-col-3 w-col-stack no-left-padding"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="gray-line"></div>

    <div class="form-label ">Surface type:</div>
    <div class="form-options">
        <div class="form-right-margin w-checkbox">
            <input id="SurfaceType" name="SurfaceType[]" class="demoInputBox" value="Tub" type="checkbox">
            <label for="Tub" class="w-form-label">Tub</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-right-margin w-checkbox">
            <input id="SurfaceType" name="SurfaceType[]" class="demoInputBox" value="Tile" type="checkbox">
            <label for="Tile" class="w-form-label">Tile</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-right-margin w-checkbox">
            <input id="SurfaceType" name="SurfaceType[]" class="demoInputBox" value="Sink" type="checkbox">
            <label for="Sink" class="w-form-label">Sink</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-right-margin w-checkbox">
            <input id="SurfaceType" name="SurfaceType[]" class="demoInputBox" value="Claw_Foot" type="checkbox">
            <label for="Claw Foot" class="w-form-label">Claw Foot</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-right-margin w-checkbox">
            <input id="SurfaceType" name="SurfaceType[]" class="demoInputBox" value="Counter_Top" type="checkbox">
            <label for="Counter Top" class="w-form-label">Counter Top</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-right-margin w-checkbox">
            <input id="SurfaceType" name="SurfaceType[]" class="demoInputBox" value="Jacuzzi" type="checkbox">
            <label for="Jacuzzi" class="w-form-label">Jacuzzi</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-right-margin w-checkbox">
            <input id="SurfaceType" name="SurfaceType[]" class="demoInputBox" value="Regrout" type="checkbox">
            <label for="Regrout" class="w-form-label">Regrout</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-right-margin w-checkbox">
            <input id="SurfaceType" name="SurfaceType[]" class="demoInputBox" value="Caulking" type="checkbox">
            <label for="Caulking" class="w-form-label" >Caulking</label> 
        </div>
        <div class="w-checkbox">
            <input id="SurfaceType" name="SurfaceType[]" class="demoInputBox" value="Other" type="checkbox">
            <label for="Other" class="w-form-label">Other</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gray-line"></div>
    <div class="form-options">
        <div class="form-right-margin-2">
            <div class="form-label">Has the tub / surface been reglazed before? :</div>
            <div class="form-options">
                <div class="form-right-margin w-radio">
                    <input id="ReglazedBefore" name="ReglazedBefore" value="Yes" class="demoInputBox" type="radio">
                    <label for="Yes" class="w-form-label">Yes</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-right-margin w-radio">
                    <input id="ReglazedBefore" name="ReglazedBefore" value="No" class="demoInputBox" type="radio">
                    <label for="No" class="w-form-label" >No</label>
                </div>
                <div class="w-radio">
                    <input id="ReglazedBefore" name="ReglazedBefore" value="Unknown"  class="demoInputBox" type="radio">
                    <label for="Unknown" class="w-form-label" >Unknown</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>   
            <div class="form-label"> Is the tub covered with:</div>
                <div class="form-options">
                    <div class="form-right-margin w-radio">
                        <input id="TubCovered" name="TubCovered" value="Curtains"  class="demoInputBox" type="radio">
                        <label for="Curtains" class="w-form-label">Curtains</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-right-margin w-radio">
                        <input id="TubCovered" name="TubCovered" value="Glass Door"  class="demoInputBox" type="radio">
                        <label for="Glass Door" class="w-form-label" >Glass door</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-radio">
                        <input id="TubCovered" name="TubCovered" value="Unknown" class="demoInputBox" type="radio">
                        <label for="Unknown" class="w-form-label">Unknown</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="gray-line"></div>

        <div class="form-options">
            <div class="form-right-margin-3">
                <div class="form-label">Do you need to recaulk your bath tub?</div>
                <div class="form-options">
                    <div class="form-right-margin w-radio">
                        <input id="Recaulk" name="Recaulk" value="Yes" class="demoInputBox" type="radio">
                        <label for="Yes" class="w-form-label">Yes</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-right-margin w-radio">
                        <input id="Recaulk" name="Recaulk" value="No" class="demoInputBox" type="radio">
                        <label for="No" class="w-form-label">No</label>
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <p>Please note: tub recaulking is 75$ extra</p> 
            </div>  
            <div class="form-right-margin-3">   
                <div class="form-label"> Do you need non skid treatment for your tub?</div>
                <div class="form-options">
                    <div class=" form-right-margin w-radio">
                        <input id="NonSkid" name="NonSkid" value="Yes"  class="demoInputBox" type="radio">
                        <label for="Yes" class="w-form-label">Yes</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-right-margin w-radio">
                        <input id="NonSkid" name="NonSkid" value="No"  class="demoInputBox" type="radio">
                        <label for="No" class="w-form-label">No</label>
                    </div>              
                </div>
                <p>Please note:  non skid treatment is 75$ extra</p>    
            </div>  
            <div>   
                <div class="form-label"> Does your building has elevator?</div>
                <div class="form-options">
                    <div class=" form-right-margin w-radio">
                        <input id="Elevator" name="Elevator" value="Yes" class="demoInputBox" type="radio">
                        <label for="Yes" class="w-form-label">Yes</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-right-margin w-radio">
                        <input id="Elevator" name="Elevator" value="No" class="demoInputBox" type="radio">
                        <label for="No" class="w-form-label">No</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-radio">
                        <input id="Elevator" name="Elevator" value="Unknown" class="demoInputBox" type="radio">
                        <label for="Unknown" class="w-form-label">Unknown</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="gray-line"></div>

        <div class="form-label ">Additional Comments:</div>
            <div>
                <textarea name="comments" id="comments" class="demoInputBox width"
                          cols="60" rows="4" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit To Book Appointment " class="submit-button btnAction" />
            </div>
</form>
```

The form is submitted through Ajax as expected, but I'm not getting any of the radio and checkbox values returned. What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

1. Get the values from the radio buttons and checkboxes returned in my PHP script.
2. Make both the radio buttons and checkboxes mandatory through jQuery

I've tried to achieve this myself with:

```
$(document).ready(function (e){
    $("#frmEnquiry").on('submit',(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#loader-icon').show();
        var valid;  
        valid = validateContact();

        if(valid) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "book-appointmentCopy.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:  new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                success: function(data){
                    $("#mail-status").html(data);
                    $('#loader-icon').hide();
                },
                error: function(){}             
            });
        }
    }));

    function validateContact() {
        var valid = true;   
        $(".demoInputBox").css('background-color','');
        $(".info").html('');
        $("#userName").removeClass("invalid");
        $("#userEmail").removeClass("invalid");
        $("#phone").removeClass("invalid");
        $("#zip").removeClass("invalid");
        $("#Date").removeClass("invalid");
        $("#Time").removeClass("invalid");
        $("#SurfaceType").removeClass("invalid");
        $("#ReglazedBefore").removeClass("invalid");
        $("#TubCovered").removeClass("invalid");
        $("#Recaulk").removeClass("invalid");
        $("#NonSkid").removeClass("invalid");
        $("#Elevator").removeClass("invalid");
        $("#comments").removeClass("invalid");

        if(!$("#userName").val()) {
            $("#userName").addClass("invalid");
            $("#userName").attr("title","Required");
            valid = false;
        }
        if(!$("#phone").val()) {
            $("#phone").addClass("invalid");
            $("#phone").attr("title","Required");
            valid = false;
        }
        if(!$("#userEmail").val()) {
            $("#userEmail").addClass("invalid");
            $("#userEmail").attr("title","Required");
            valid = false;
        }
        if(!$("#userEmail").val().match(/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/)) {
            $("#userEmail").addClass("invalid");
            $("#userEmail").attr("title","Invalid Email");
            valid = false;
        }
        if(!$("#zip").val()) {
            $("#zip").addClass("invalid");
            $("#zip").attr("title","Required");
            valid = false;
        }
        if(!$("#Date").val()) {
            $("#Date").addClass("invalid");
            $("#Date").attr("title","Required");
            valid = false;
        }
        if(!$("#Time").val()) {
            $("#Time").addClass("invalid");
            $("#Time").attr("title","Required");
            valid = false;
        }
        if(!$("#SurfaceType").val()) {
            $("#SurfaceType").addClass("invalid");
            $("#SurfaceType").attr("title","Required");
            valid = false;
        }
        if(!$("#ReglazedBefore").val()) {
            $("#ReglazedBefore").addClass("invalid");
            $("#ReglazedBefore").attr("title","Required");
            valid = false;
        }
        if(!$("#TubCovered").val()) {
            $("#TubCovered").addClass("invalid");
            $("#TubCovered").attr("title","Required");
            valid = false;
        }
        if(!$("#Recaulk").val()) {
            $("#Recaulk").addClass("invalid");
            $("#Recaulk").attr("title","Required");
            valid = false;
        }
        if(!$("#NonSkid").val()) {
            $("#NonSkid").addClass("invalid");
            $("#NonSkid").attr("title","Required");
            valid = false;
        }
        if(!$("#Elevator").val()) {
            $("#Elevator").addClass("invalid");
            $("#Elevator").attr("title","Required");
            valid = false;
        }
        if(!$("#comments").val()) {
            $("#comments").addClass("invalid");
            $("#comments").attr("title","Required");
            valid = false;
        }

        return valid;
    }
});
```

Unfortunely this doesn't seem to work for radio buttons and checkboxes. Did I do something wrong? Here's my PHP script that's handling the form:

```
<?php

$message=
    'Name:  '.$_POST['userName'].'<br /><br />
    Phone Number:   '.$_POST['phone'].'<br /><br />
    E-Mail: '.$_POST['userEmail'].'<br /><br />
    ZIP / City of job site: '.$_POST['zip'].'<br /><br />
    Date:   '.$_POST['Date'].'<br /><br />
    Time:   '.$_POST['Time'].'<br /><br />
    Surface type:   '.($_POST['SurfaceType']).'<br /><br />
    Has the tub / surface been reglazed before?:    '.$_POST['ReglazedBefore'].'<br /><br />
    Is the tub covered with:    '.$_POST['TubCovered'].'<br /><br />
    Do you need to recaulk your bath tub?:  '.$_POST['Recaulk'].'<br /><br />
    Do you need non skid treatment for your tub?:   '.$_POST['NonSkid'].'<br /><br />
    Does your building has elevator?:   '.$_POST['Elevator'].'<br /><br />
    Additional Comments:    '.$_POST['comments'].'
';

require('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Port     = 465;  
$mail->Username = "mymail@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "mypass";
$mail->Host     = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Mailer   = "smtp";
$mail->SetFrom($_POST["userEmail"], $_POST["userName"]);
$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST["userEmail"], $_POST["userName"]);
$mail->AddAddress("myemailaddress");     // Where to send it - Recipient
$mail->Subject = " Form - https://www..com/";      // Subject (which isn't required)  
$mail->WordWrap   = 80;
$mail->MsgHTML($message);
foreach ($_FILES["attachment"]["name"] as $k => $v) {
    $mail->AddAttachment( $_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"][$k], $_FILES["attachment"]["name"][$k] );
}

$mail->IsHTML(true);

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.html\">";
} else {
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contact-thanks.html\">";
}

?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to avoid empty input values?

Comment: Please include all _relevant_ code inside your question. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Don't expect us to go dig around the internet for it ourselves.

Comment: What have you tried, what is the change you made to the php and js that didn't work. SO isn't here to do your work, but it is here to give you pointers

Comment: thank you for your reply. i need all fields and at least one checkbox and radio button to be mandatory or required.  i mean i need user to fill all fields and select at least one checkbox and radio button.

Comment: And how would you like to achieve this? Do you want to force your users to fill something in? In that case, this is a Javascript question. Do you want to verify serverside that it's filled in? That makes it a PHP question. As you can see, you'll need to be _specific_ about what it is you want. We're not magical wizards that can read your mind you know.

Comment: "*If someone could let me know where and what code is to be added*" This is too broad for this site unfortunately as the answers can be opinionated. You need to write your code yourself really based on your specific form requirements and code setup and design. Then ask any specific issues you face with your code.

Comment: thank you for your replies. this is the first time i am asking a question here, i am sorry about not being specific. basically i work with html and css but this time i am having to work with this form. i need user to must fill all fields and select at least one checkbox and radio button and i want all those values to be sent to my email.

Comment: Great! Now read all the comments again. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50299916/edit) your question and show us exactly what you've tried and where it went wrong. As said before: We're not here to do your job for you. If your question starts with _"How do I.."_, Stack Overflow is the wrong place to ask. If your question starts with _"I've tried this, it didn't work, what did I do wrong?"_, Stack Overflow is the place to be and we're more than happy to help you out.

Comment: thank you icecub for guiding me about how to ask here.

Comment: It's ok man. Our comments may come across a little harsh, but it's not intended like that. Stack Overflow has a very specific set of guidelines on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It keeps the website clean and professional. Not just for you and us, but also for the people that have the same question as you and find your question on the website. As a new user, it's ok to make mistakes. Don't let it get you down. You'll learn and become a better user in the future :)

Comment: i am completely editing my question again.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere! So you did _try_ something yourself! It clearly shows in your Javascript that you've tried making your form elements required by your users. That's what we wanted to see! :)

Comment: :) yes i have tried alot and have given it days not hours :)

Comment: i have fully edited my question now.

Comment: Do you mind if I edit your question further as to make it more clear?

Comment: ok icecub you can edit it.

Comment: Alright, working on it. May take some time. There's a lot to go through in there.

Comment: ok thank you for being so helpful!

Comment: No problem. I'm editing your question so you can learn from it. After that, I will see if I can answer it for you as well.

Comment: Alright, edit is complete :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright. First lets address your first question: *Get the values from the radio buttons and checkboxes returned in my PHP script.*

The reason you're not getting the values returned in your PHP script is because these POST variables represent an [Array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and not a normal string. So instead of using `$_POST['SurfaceType']` to get the value, you'll need to use `$_POST['SurfaceType'][0]`. Or, for simplicity, you could use [Implode()](http://php.net/implode) to join the array elements into a normal string, like so:

`$SurfaceType = implode(',' , $_POST['SurfaceType']);`

Now `$SurfaceType` will contain the value and you can use it inside `$message` like you did with all the other variables.

Now lets move on to your second question: *Make both the radio buttons and checkboxes mandatory through jQuery*

You've tried to use:

```
if(!$("#SurfaceType").val()) {
    $("#SurfaceType").addClass("invalid");
    $("#SurfaceType").attr("title","Required");
    valid = false;
}
```

But that doesn't work on radio buttons or checkboxes. It's because you actually need to verify if they're *checked* and not if they have a value. So instead (credits to [Shaun Forsyth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1622173/shaun-forsyth) for this one) you should use:

```
if ($('input[name="SurfaceType[]"]:checked').length == 0){
    $("#SurfaceType").addClass("invalid").attr("title","Required");
    valid = false;
}
```

Lastly I wanted to add that you might want to replace all `<br />` elements inside `$message` with `\n`. When you're sending an email, you use \n to create a new line.

It's been quite the journey for you tonight and you had to show a lot of patience, but I hope you've learned something and become one of our many outstanding members here on Stack Overflow!

Comment: Sorry, missed that, respect for the more detailed response.

Comment: Hello icecub, thank you so much for the answer, you are awesome!!! i would really like to thank you for your precious time and effort you made for me!

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can do something like.

```
if ($('input[name="SurfaceType[]"]:checked').length == 0){
    $("#SurfaceType").addClass("invalid").attr("title","Required");
    valid = false;
}
```

In your php you can do something like

```
Surface type:   '.implode(',' , $_POST['SurfaceType']).'<br /><br />
```

You shouldn't repeat ids in elements in the page

Comment: +1 from me because I've borrowed some code from your answer into mine. If you read all the comments, I promissed to answer OP's question and added some more detailed explanation to it.

Comment: Hello Shaun Forsyth, i would also like to thank you, your answer helped me alot! its working now.

But when i am trying to submit the form without selecting checkboxes it just gets stuck but i do not get any error message that i should select the checkboxes.

also you said i should not repeat ids, I removed ids from every checkbox and put the id in the main div but now i am getting this error message for a moment although form is submitting.  

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/user/public_html/book-appointmentCopy.php